# Docker - Unable to ping anything on the host's subnet from inside a container

Tags: docker, networking, routes, docker-compose

I have a Mac host machine with a 192.168.11.10 IP Address.

I have a docker-compose project running there with the default network configuration. I need to connect to a device on the 192.168.11.11 IP Address from within the docker container.

From within the container, I am able to reach anything in the outside world, except the hosts on the 192.168.11.X subnet.  I don't want to expose my network using network=host, since there are like 6 different services and I prefer to keep them separated.

I have also tried connecting to the 192.168.11.11 device from an outside network through a VPN to discard any routing issues on the device's configuration and that works ok.

This is a section of my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/php/php.docker
    links:
      - socket
      - horizon
    volumes:
      - './:/var/www'
```

And my php.docker file:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mariadb-client libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev libpng-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql soap simplexml zip gd
```

The ifconfig from my docker container is like so:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
94: eth0@if95: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:18:00:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.24.0.6/16 brd 172.24.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

A traceroute to google.com:

```
traceroute to google.com (216.58.192.46), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.24.0.1 (172.24.0.1)  1.254 ms  1.169 ms  1.136 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  10.130.4.9 (10.130.4.9)  15.110 ms  14.998 ms  15.173 ms
 6  10.192.16.97 (10.192.16.97)  16.829 ms 10.192.16.101 (10.192.16.101)  13.281 ms 10.192.16.97 (10.192.16.97)  13.230 ms
 7  10.192.37.162 (10.192.37.162)  14.961 ms  15.365 ms  15.946 ms
 8  10.192.55.42 (10.192.55.42)  10.349 ms  11.927 ms  11.740 ms
 9  10.192.55.53 (10.192.55.53)  13.189 ms  11.223 ms  9.438 ms
10  * * *
11  ix-et-9-1-5-0.tcore2.mln-miami.as6453.net (66.110.72.129)  45.735 ms  44.555 ms  46.883 ms
12  72.14.215.97 (72.14.215.97)  44.955 ms  44.353 ms  45.396 ms
13  108.170.249.1 (108.170.249.1)  35.341 ms 108.170.249.17 (108.170.249.17)  35.471 ms  38.107 ms
14  108.170.226.225 (108.170.226.225)  37.641 ms 108.170.226.229 (108.170.226.229)  36.956 ms 108.170.226.225 (108.170.226.225)  36.224 ms
15  mia07s46-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.192.46)  49.190 ms  47.804 ms  46.801 ms
```

A traceroute to my device throws this:

```
traceroute to 192.168.11.11 (192.168.11.11), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.24.0.1 (172.24.0.1)  1.229 ms  1.026 ms  0.964 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After banging my head for days, it seems it was some misconfiguration on my Mac.  I fixed it by resetting the whole Docker environment:

(Caution: this will delete all your containers, images and networks)

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker network prune -f
docker rmi -f $(docker images --filter dangling=true -qa)
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls --filter dangling=true -q)
```